# Bit manipulation and Flags testing in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, flags, bitflags

Suppose I have two variables of type `int`, `a` and `b`, and a flag `F`.

```
#define F <something>

int a = <something> ;
int b = <something> ;
```

What is a simple way to test that both `a` and `b`, have the flag `F`, or none of them has it?

To test if both of them have it, I can use something like:

```
if ( a & b & F )
```

To test if none of them has it, I can use something like:

```
if ( !((a & F) || (b & F)) )
```

And the whole test becomes:

```
if ( (a & b & F) &&  !((a & F) || (b & F)) )
```

But this looks, too long and too complicated. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: not xor................

Comment: Why `&&` is used despite of you want to test *or*?

Comment: Maybe add the test for the directive in isolation?

Comment: Is it granteed that exactly one bit in `F` is 1, or none or multiple bits in `F` can be 1?

Comment: @MikeCAT it's garanteed that `F` is non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test for "none of them has it" can be

```
!((a | b) & F)
```

Merge the flags, mask and flip the logic.

---

The whole test can be written using xor. (Thanks to Martin James for the idea)

```
!((a ^ b) & F)
```

This means "not (exactly one of `a` or `b` has `F`)"

Comment: `!((a | b) & F)` Is this De Morgan's laws? because I think `!((a | b) & F)` is equivalent to `!( (a&F) | (b&F) )` and not `!( (a&F) || (b&F) )`

Comment: @BiteBytes None of `!( (a&F) | (a&F) )` and `!( (a&F) || (a&F) )` is equivalent to `!((a | b) & F)`: both of the first two uses `a` twice while the last one uses `a` and `b`.

Comment: @BiteBytes `(a | b) & F` is equivalent to `(a & F) | (b & F)` and isn't equivalent to `(a & F) || (b & F)`, the difference is that `|` operator does bitwise OR and `||` operator does logic OR. But adding `!` operator, which does logic NOT, to all of them, all should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for bit equality, which can be tested by applying XOR operator `^`, inverting the result, and masking.

`a ^ b` sets bits to 1 only where the corresponding bits of `a` and `b` are different. For corresponding bits that are the same the result bit will be set to zero.

If you invert the result, you'd get ones in positions of equal bits:

```
~(a ^ b)
```

The only thing that remains is to mask with `F`, and check for equality:

```
if ((~(a ^ b) & F) == F) {
    ... // All bits indicated by F are set to the same value in a and b
}
```

Comment: why checking for equality? wouldn't `if (~(a ^ b) & F))` be enough?

Comment: Without an equality check at the end you would get a "true" when some, but not necessarily all, the bits have a match. It would also not work for F of zero (when no bits are checked the answer should be "true").

Comment: `~(a ^ b) & F == F`  - it is incorrect it is the same as `~(a ^ b) & 1`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight even when corrected it gives the worst code :)  https://godbolt.org/g/8ugA7r

Comment: operator precedence issue: change `~(a ^ b) & F == F)` to `(~(a ^ b) & F) == F)`, which is decidedly less readable than `!((a ^ b) & F)`

Comment: @PeterJ why is that? `==` has lower precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one

```
!((a & F) ^ (b & F))
```

Comment: More readable but possibly one more opcode than `!((a ^ b) & F)`.  Also a bit error prone as the elegant symmetry might make the reader assume that it would work for different flags as in `!((a & F1) ^ (b & F2))` which is not true.

Comment: Yes - it is intentional as OP is learning bitwise operations. It gives the same output despite of optimisation level. https://godbolt.org/g/SmXL9N

Comment: interesting how gcc unlike clang produces the same code at `-O0` and clang produces the same code at `-O2` unlike gcc that shares the code with a `jmp`.

Comment: @chqrlie the chosen solution does not work :) and produces when corrected the worst code

Comment: @chqrlie I have tested only gcc